# How can I solve my Php - Mysql Filter query problem?

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a problem.
I have a mysql command as below.
The information in the column I call $birim is not synchronized with the value in the $birim variable.
It comes with other information.

What I want is this:

The birim is "that" and the search word is this or that or that.

I want to run a query of .

Please help me .

Thanks already for your help.

```
$aranacak=$_POST['aranacak'];
$birim="Kutuphane Adi";
$getir=$baglan->prepare("SELECT * 
                        from eserler 
                        WHERE birim=? 
                        AND baslik like ? 
                        OR esersahibi like ? 
                        OR konu like ? 
                        OR konum like ?");
$getir->execute(array($birim,'%'.$aranacak.'%', 
                            '%'.$aranacak.'%', 
                            '%'.$aranacak.'%', 
                            '%'.$aranacak.'%'));
while ($getircek=$getir->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    #############################################
?>
```

Comment: Only if you can read it can you hope to debug it

Comment: If you are using AND as well as OR in the WHERE clause, it is always better to use `( )` to ensure the logic is applied as you intended it

Comment: I would be grateful if you could write a small example.

Comment: we're not entirely sure what your logic should be, but this would be a start:`WHERE birim=? AND (baslik like ? OR esersahibi like ? OR konu like ? OR konum like ?)`.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what logic should be applied but something like `WHERE birim=?  (AND baslik like ? OR esersahibi like ? OR konu like ? OR konum like ?)");`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your help and such a quick turnaround.
With the help of WOUNDEDStevenJones and RiggsFolly I found my problem.

Solution to the problem:

```
WHERE unit=? AND (title like ? OR author like ? OR subject like ? OR location like ?)");
```

This way it worked correctly.

Thank you guys, thank you so much for everything.

I was about to go crazy. :)